# How to hint that there's more beyond what you see in a scroll view?

Tags: ios, scrolling, content, hints

I'm developing an (iOS) app that mainly consists of a `UIScrollView`. The view is paged and the scroll bar turned off, so currently there is nothing to indicate to the user that they can scroll down and see more stuff.

I'm thinking about making the app, on startup, 'bounce' the scroll view - down then up, quickly- so the user gets a glimpse of what's under the current content, and that *there is in fact more stuff*.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: What content does your app have?

Comment: @rk. The app consists of 'tiles', arranged in columns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to communicate below the fold content.

- The most natural way I have seen is just have **content overflow the fold**, so some part of it is visible while some is missing. This just tells you there is stuff down there.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff26xZ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

- If you are dealing with **plain text, just cut the last line halfway** across its height (imagine seeing top half of a strikethrough text line). It has similar visual que as the half missing content.
- If you want to use interactions, then the one you mentioned, **bouncing**, should be a good one. Also, if there is not much content below the fold, you can do a **smooth scrolling from bottom to top**(or vice versa) on app launch (remember the console games of old, they had the level preview in which you saw the entire level scroll before you begin).

Answer (score 6):

I do agree that users will tend to scroll regardless of any indication, however if you still want to use any sort of indication, this is way I suggest.

The fold is a good idea when you have a fixed screen, however, the apple products have now many screen sizes (iphone5 and the ipad)so it will be harder to calculate the grid. Is possible to do, just have this in mind.

An alternative could be to add a subtle icon like the one in the image attached. It can appear only when you are not scrolling and change upwards/downwards depending where on the canvas the user is.

[image: icon]

Answer (score 5):

That boucing stuff is scary. The user is never going to expect that on first time and it is useless when they get used to your application.

I cannot prove that idea is not going to work though. I would propose you do something like this:

The tiles are within a non ended canvas that suggest there is something else when scrolling.

[image: mockup]

That said : I am pretty sure iPhone enthusiasts know how to scroll and do it like a relfex.

If you are still afraid that they do not go to the bottom of your page an option is to add a "scroll bar alike" that shows were you are and there is more to see :

[image: mockup]

I know the mockup is lame but you get the idea, if you do not comment.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of showing the scrollbar when entering the screen and letting it fade. (Just like when you scroll and let go)
It is THE scroll indicator.

It may be a problem it is time based... so the information will disappear over time...

(Whoops... you are talking about the scrollbar being turned off... well maybe interesting for others)